# rm: cannot remove '0': Operation not permitted

Tags: permissions, root, rm

**Issue**

Impossible to remove folder as `root`.

```
root@local:/home/hosek/app/firefox.bak/updates# ls -la
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 hosek hosek 4096 pro  9 14:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 hosek hosek 4096 pro 10 11:06 ..
drwxrwxrwx 2 hosek hosek 4096 pro 10 11:06 0
root@local:/home/hosek/app/firefox.bak/updates# rm -rf 0
rm: cannot remove '0': Operation not permitted
root@local:/home/hosek/app/firefox.bak/updates#
```

Why? Thanks.

Comment: Solution founded here. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29902/unable-to-delete-file-even-when-running-as-root Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that the directory is still in use, and therefore cannot be deleted.

What happens if you use the fuser command to see any PIDs running in the directory? Example:

```
MyTestServer: cd /home/postgres/logs
MyTestServer: fuser .
/home/postgres/logs: 40470c
```

Comment: Thank you, but I removed it already.